# PHP Debugger similar to ASP.NET

Tags: php, ide, debugging

In Visual Studio, I can start the debugger and am able to debug any page I want. Say I launch index.aspx, I can step through the code. Then I click on a button that navigates to page1.aspx, I can step through the code whenever a breakpoint is hit.

I am trying to find a similar tool for php. I tried using xDebug and Zend on Eclipse, but I could do is debug one file at a time. Even though I chose Debug As -> PHP Web Page, I can debug only the page I chose. Then if I navigate to other pages, the debugger won't stop at my breakpoints.

Am I missing something here? Is there an IDE that supports this feature for php websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse PDT you have to begin debugging on your index page, then don't close your debugging session and replace the eclipse browser url with the url of the page you need to debug.

You can also access to the page you need to debug by clicking links from your first page.

It works for me with Zend debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Eclipse PHP IDE](http://eclipse.org/proposals/php-ide/)!

Comment: I have PDT installed, but my problem is that I can debug only one page.

Answer (score 0):

[NuSphere's PHPEd](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm) has a pretty decent debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to Visual Studio, you have the [VS.php plugin](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/jcx/) which was already good, 1 year ago when I saw someone use it.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 6.8 do it, if I'm not wrong. I don't remember if you can start the debug from a page different than the index page but, afterward it follows the page changes (I'm sure of this).

Edit: I've checked: Netbeans 6.8 (I think it works with the 6.9 version too) + xdebug2 => it works like a charm.